# SQlite difference between FALSE and 0

Tags: sqlite

these both statements seem to make a difference, but I do not yet get why:

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
```

seems to behave differently than:

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

can anyone shed some light on this - I thought FALSE is 0 and TRUE is 1 - but this boolean seems to have >= 4 states:

```
➜  ~  sqlite3               
SQLite version 3.8.7.4 2014-12-09 01:34:36
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE FOO ( id INTEGER );sqlite> INSERT INTO FOO ( id ) VALUES (1);
sqlite> select * from FOO;
1
sqlite> ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;sqlite> select * from FOO;
1|FALSE
sqlite> ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED2 BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
sqlite> select * from FOO;
1|FALSE|0
sqlite> ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED3 BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE;
sqlite> select * from FOO;
1|FALSE|0|TRUE
sqlite> ALTER TABLE FOO ADD COLUMN DELETED4 BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;
sqlite> select * from FOO;
1|FALSE|0|TRUE|1

sqlite> select * from FOO WHERE DELETED;
sqlite> select * from FOO WHERE DELETED2;
sqlite> select * from FOO WHERE DELETED3;
sqlite> select * from FOO WHERE DELETED4;
1|FALSE|0|TRUE|1
```

Comment: The internal storage is `int`. The DB probably recognizes the data type and outputs `false` for `0`

Comment: I doubt this is actually TRUE or FALSE as such, try replacing FALSE with MONKEYDOODLE in one of the alter table statements and check the results.

Comment: There's no Bool type in sqlite (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) use zero and non-zero for false and true.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen interesting: sqlite> select * from FOO;
1|FALSE|0|TRUE|1|MONKEYDOODLE
- is this then some kind of enum? this is not a string column - still confused .. but thanks for the pointer

Comment: If you execute a `.dump` you'll see that those values are actually strings. Also note that SQLite does not really care all that much about the *type* of the *values*  you put into those columns. Try creating a numeric column and adding some text to it for instance.

Comment: This is madness - cannot believe what I just saw - how can a boolean/integer row store strings

Comment: SQLite doesn't use fixed types for columns. From the documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): "Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class." They operate with storage classes which are bit more general and specify more how a column operates than any restrictions on the data type. A numeric storage class may impact things like sorting and indexing but it will not prevent you from storing text into the column.

Comment: Yup, the type declarations are all but decoration, the engine is basically type agnostic.

Comment: Try just naming your own types: `CREATE TABLE test (id MYPRIMARYKEY);` It will work just fine, though again, the storage class is not known so it may *behave*  slightly different in regards to sorting and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why exactly SQLite allows these `ALTER TABLE` statements to run as shown I don't know but the missing piece of the puzzle here is that those `FALSE` and `TRUE` values will be stored as *strings*.

Try this in the SQLite command line tool:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, xx boolean not null default TRUE);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1)
.dump
```

You'll get this output:

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, xx boolean not null default TRUE);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'TRUE');
COMMIT;
```

As you can see, the `TRUE` value there is stored as a string.

Now, let's try to query for the `TRUE` value:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE xx = TRUE
```

this gives this error message:

```
Error: no such column: TRUE
```

So in short, `TRUE` or `FALSE` are not magical constants in SQLite SQL syntax for the boolean values. Why the `ALTER TABLE` statements allow for them to be specified without quotes I don't know, there's probably a good reason.

Here's the example from my comment:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN xy INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT MONKEYDOODLE;
```

Output from `.dump`:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (id integer, xx boolean not null default TRUE, xy INTEGER NOT
NULL DEFAULT MONKEYDOODLE);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'TRUE','MONKEYDOODLE');
COMMIT;
```

One final piece of the puzzle is also that SQLite doesn't really prevent you from storing values of different data types in the same column.

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> Any column in an SQLite version 3 database, except an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, may be used to store a value of any storage class.

You can see this in effect here:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id integer);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('test');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (DATE());
INSERT INTO test VALUES (10.5);
```

This is the output from `.dump`:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test (id integer);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('test');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES('2015-07-20');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(10.5);
COMMIT;
```